# How to update dynamic changing fields of json objects using React setState?

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I have an object that its fields change dynamically, e.g.,

```
var Obj = {f1:"", f2:""} or  var Obj = {f1:"", f2:"", f3:"" } etc
```

An input field appears dynamically on screen for every field of the object.
I want to set the state of the object with the values that users enter in each field. How can I do this? I have tried the following code but it doesn't always works correctly.

```
for (var key in this.state.Obj) {
        if (this.state.Obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            this.setState({
                Obj: update(this.state.Obj, {[key]: {$set: window.$('[name='+key+']')[0].value}}),
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should consider using an `onChange` handler on each of the input elements, rather than jQuery selectors.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you should use an `onChange` on whatever input fields you need. You could do something like:

```
<input
  type="text"
  value={this.state.Obj.f1}
  onChange={(e) => {
    // Make sure you keep values from other fields
    var object = this.state.Obj;

    // Modify the value on the object
    object.f1 = e.target.value;

    // Update the state
    this.setState({ Obj: object });
  }}
/>
```